# Bitmap Image of Hidden Process Window c++

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap, bmp

As the title reads, I'm trying to capture an image of a hidden process window. Every time I try and capture a screenshot of the hidden notepad window with `SW_HIDE` set, I get a black image.

Is there any alternative to hiding the window from the user and still being able to capture the windows image?

```
 /// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
RECT rc;
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("Untitled - Notepad"));
if (hwnd == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Can't Find Window";
    return 0;
}

HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
if (hdc)
{
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    if (hdcMem)
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);

        HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
        if (hbitmap)
        {
            SelectObject(hdcMem, hbitmap);

            PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcMem, 0);
            if (OpenClipboard(hwnd) != 0) {
                EmptyClipboard();
                SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hbitmap);
                CloseClipboard();
            }
            DeleteObject(hbitmap);
        }
        DeleteObject(hdcMem);
    }
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
}
```

Comment: You can't capture a hidden window, as it is not rendered onscreen. You would have to make the window visible first, and either move it off-screen, or give it an alpha opacity of 1, so the user can't see it but Windows can.

Comment: After further investigation, I have found that it is possible with PrintWindow("", WM_PAINT). I am yet trying to achieve this.

Comment: those are not valid parameters for `PrintWindow()`. And `PrintWindow()` does not always work, as many windows don't implement the `WM_PRINT`/`WM_PRINTCLIENT` messages.

Comment: I guess you could try using the [DWM Thumbnail API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/thumbnail-ovw).